# Change order when applying templates?

Tags: xml, xslt

For example i have the following xml:

```
<items>
  <item value="1">
  <item value="2">
  <item value="3" start="true">
  <item value="4">
  <item value="5">
</items>
```

And xsl like this:

```
<ul>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
</ul>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <li><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></li>
</xsl:template>
```

This outputs the items in document order. However I would like it to start at the specified position, so the order of the output would be 3, 4, 5, 1, 2. It this possible without having to change the order in the document?

Thanks!

Edit:

The following works:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="item">
  <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="position()-count(../item[@start]/preceding-sibling::item)+count(../item)*boolean(position()&lt;=count(../item[@start]/preceding-sibling::item)"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: Could you explain further the logic of the required order? If you start at 3, why are 1 and 2 included at all? If the need to be included, why do they come after 4 and 5?.

Comment: Yeah the example is an abstraction. Basically it's a list of images and I want to be able to select which image appears first.

Comment: So does the internal order of the images that aren't tagged as `start` matter at all?

Comment: Yeah it would be nice if the order is kept. But I think I've almost solved it, see my edit.

Comment: I am sorry, but that doesn't answer my question. In your "abstract" example, the order is **not** kept. To keep the order, but make an exception for the tagged item, the order would be 3, 1, 2, 4, 5.

Comment: No I mean cyclic order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change:

```
<ul>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
</ul>
```

to:

```
<ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@start='true']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@start='true']/following-sibling::item"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@start='true']/preceding-sibling::item"/>
</ul>
```

That will produce the expected result in the given example. Whether that's the rule you want to apply in general is not clear to me.

---

### Added:

> What about if the start tag is optional? So if there isn't one it
>   outputs in document order but if there is one it starts there?

Well, you could split the decision tree like this:

```
<ul>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="item[@start='true']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@start='true']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@start='true']/following-sibling::item"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@start='true']/preceding-sibling::item"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</ul>
```

Or, if you prefer, you could shorten this to:

```
<ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@start='true']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@start='true']/following-sibling::item"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@start='true']/preceding-sibling::item"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[not(../item[@start='true'])]"/>
</ul>
```

Both of these avoid the potentially expensive `xsl:sort` instruction - not to mention the insanely convoluted calculation such sort would require.

Comment: Thanks! What about if the start tag is optional? So if there isn't one it outputs in document order but if there is one it starts there?